# How can I manage versions of file on artifactory without adding "-" patrameters

Tags: artifactory

I want to be able to manage couple of versions for same file.
The common way is to add "-" parameters, I am looking for possibility for a review of the versions of the same file and ability to deploy not the latest version.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a [custom layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) to manage versions how you see fit, although note that actual versioning schemes defer from client to client so it really depends on the client that you're using.

Layouts will enable you to deploy and resolve from Artifactory based on the versioning scheme you defined (as long as the client you use supports it) - you will also be able to use Artifactory-specific features such as [Version Cleanup](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Manipulating+Artifacts#ManipulatingArtifacts-DeletingaVersion).